# GWT Generators - Determine Whether a Class is Referenced Anywhere

Tags: gwt, reflection

I have GWT project that uses Generators to create light dynamic reflection objects.

I was wondering if anybody knows of a way to determine whether or not a particular class is referenced in the dependency tree beginning at all EntryPoints.  If I could do this, I could avoid generating reflection data for classes that will never be used anyway.

My understanding is that when GWT does its compiling, it performs a similar check so that it can reduce the total size of the compiled code, but I haven't been able to find any related methods in TypeOracle or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect method of accomplishing what you are getting at. I believe each GWT module, is fully packaged into a regular java package. You can use

```
TypeOracle.findPackage(String pkgName)
```

to get the JPackage instance, and on that instance you use findType(String typeName) to see if a type is present in that package. If present, its likely that it is referenced in some file and GWT will compile it.

There is also this method getPackages() which returns an array of all packages known to this type oracle - therefore reachable for GWT compiler.

```
JPackage[] getPackages()
```

You can iteratively `findType()` on each package to find if the type is going to be compiled or not.

The BEST method is to define a custom annotation and whitelist all the classes that you do want to generate reflection code. You can annotate the required classes with it, and checking for that presence of annotation before generating code for it.

My favorite is to follow a naming convention over annotation, (I did both together), and thus maintain a whitelist, and make the convention (its usually a REGEX) a "setting" that can be changed however the team wants.

Comment: JMethod.isAnnotationPresent(YourAttribute.class) will help.

Comment: Problem being TypeOracle will find any class that's included, but not necessarily referenced.  I have a number of classes annotated a certain way, in a package that gets shared between several modules.  I'd rather not have to manually include/exclude which classes are actually used.